# Proclarity on Performance point

Tags: sharepoint, ssas, performancepoint, proclarity

My company wants to use Microsoft ProClarity, as I am new to BI I am not sure how to answer these question:

1. Is ProClarity still available with standalone license?
2. ProClarity is available on PerformacePoint Server 2010 (Sharepoint 2010) or not?

Please assist me.

Comment: **off topic** ? Strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Since MS bought ProClarity in 2006, it is licensed under MS Performance Point Server. I don't think you can have it as stand alone anymore.
2. Check [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/proclarity/thread/52e4eee3-2679-4917-9c76-5870029cd9b0/#8f2035f9-25ab-48a6-9201-1a0dbdd3ba39) link